# python shows none instead of empty space

Tags: python, file-handling, nonetype

I was trying a file handling exercise which converts temperature and writes it to a file. The function part of my program is:

```
def c_to_f(c):
if c< -273.15:
    pass #"That temperature doesn't make sense!"
else:
    f=c*9/5+32
    return f
```

In the exercise instructions, is asked me to not write any message in the text file when input is lower than -273.15. i.e for a set of values temperatures = [10,-20,-289,100] the desire output should be :

```
 50.0
-4.0
212.0
```

but I keep getting

```
50.0
-4.0
None
212.0
```

why is pass returning the "None" value instead of passing (doing nothing).

This is my main method:

```
file = open("temp_file.txt", "w+")
for i in temperatures:
    k = c_to_f(i)
    file.write(str(k) + "\n")
file.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Python returns `None` from functions if there is no `return` statement.

You can check to see if the value is `None` before writing the output to the file with a conditional. Also note that using file handles not in a `with` block is usually bad practice (see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)).

```
with open("temp_file.txt", "w+") as file:
    for i in temperatures:
        k = c_to_f(i)
        if k is not None:
            file.write(str(k) + "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

When you assign `k = c_to_f(i)`, what would you expect `k` to be when the `c_to_f` passes? It's `None` since you're not returning anything.

You can just skip writing the line if it is `None`.

```
for i in temperatures:
    k = c_to_f(i)
    if k:
        file.write(str(k) + "\n")
```

Comment: You're correct, I misread the question. Answer has been edited.